# Combining 2 custom M functions to parse text and classify

Tags: powerquery, m

As part of a PowerQuery data load, I would like to add a field that classifies some data into broad groups.  The data to be classified, in this case, is text, but starts with a index number, such as "01 Oranges", "02 Pears", "06 Cabbages", "08 Carrots".  The function needs to group the indexes say 1-5 into "Fruits" and 6+ into "Vegetables". While I could do this with a separate look-up table and merge, a function offers more flexibility.

The problem has two parts; (1) extracting the index and (2) making the list. I can create functions to do these separately, but have not figured out how to combine them into one. The two separate functions are shown below.

```
// (1) this function takes the index value of the input text (and has place holders for the second function
    let 
    class = (input) =>
    // find the index
    let 
        index = Number.FromText(Text.Start(input, 2))
    in 
        index
    // depending on the index, allocate the class

in class
```

```
// (2) this function allocates the index to a class

    (input) =>

    // depending on the index, allocate the class
    let band = 
        {
            {(x)=> x <= 5, "Fruit"},
            {(x)=> x > 5, "Vegetable"}
        },
        result = List.First(List.Select(band, each _{0}(input))){1}
    in 
        result
```

When I try to put the two together, I get a Eof and comma-missing errors.

```
// (1) this bit takes the index value of the input text
let 
    class = (input) =>
    // find the index
    let 
        index = Number.FromText(Text.Start(input, 2))
    in 
        index

    // depending on the index, allocate the class

// (2) this bit allocates it to a class

    class =>

    // depending on the index, allocate the class
    let band = 
        {
            {(x)=> x <= 5, "Fruit"},
            {(x)=> x > 5, "Vegetable"}
        },
        result = List.First(List.Select(band, each _{0}(input))){1}
    in 
        result
in class
```

Very grateful for your insight into combining functions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work:

```
(input) =>
let band = 
    {
        {Number.FromText(Text.Start(input, 2)) <= 5, "Fruit"},
        {Number.FromText(Text.Start(input, 2)) > 5, "Vegetable"}
    },
    result = List.Select(band, each _{0}){0}{1}
in 
    result
```

Comment: Yes - thank you.  I'd tried something like that, but couldn't get the embedded formula to work in the list!